# Do not show entries starting with . in Notepad++ FTP plugin (NppFTP)

Tags: notepad++

I am using Notepad++ FTP plugin (NppFtp) to remotely edit the files. However, it displays hidden files and directories too (those starting with .). I have tried to change this behavior by going to Profile Settings -> FTP Misc. -> changing LIST parameters to -l only, but it does not seem to have an effect.

How can I accomplish it?

Comment: Is the server you're connecting to Windows?  If so, files with leading dots are not considered hidden . . .

Comment: No, it's Linux.

Answer (score 1):

NppFTP plugin hasn't an option to hide files with lead dot. Currently no.

Comment: This feature [requested in github](https://github.com/ashkulz/NppFTP/issues/219) 180509